# Solve giving null solution when number substituted with a variable

Tags: equation-solving

I'm new to Mathematica so maybe I'm missing some crucial information but this

```
Solve[{a == 25, x^2 == a}, x]
```

gives a null solution `{ }`, while this

```
Solve[{x^2 == 25}, x]
```

gives the correct `{{x -> -5}, {x -> 5}}`. I've just restarted the kernel to make sure there aren't any symbols defined that I'm unaware of.

Why isn't the first example giving the same output as the second one?

Comment: Try: `Clear[a, x]` and `Solve[{x^2 == a}, x]` and finally: `Solve[{x^2 == a}, x] /. a -> 25`

Comment: These do work, thanks. So is it wrong to include equations such as `a==25`? Should one only use replacement rules?

Comment: `Reduce[{a == 25, x^2 == a}, x]`. The documentation for solve says: `The system expr can be any logical combination of: ... equalities, inequalities ...` but apparently it is not possible for `Solve` to see that one of the equations doesn't require solving.

Comment: Actually, cf. Nasser's answer and my comment to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is

```
ClearAll[x, a];
Solve[{a == 25, x^2 == a}, {x, a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It gave `{}` because it needed all variables to solve for (even though we know `a=25`, it just needed to see `a` in there.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. Yes, it makes sense, because `Solve` should give a set of replacement rules that makes the specified equations or inequalities true, whereas there's no way to satisfy `a==25` if you don't want `a` to be included in these output rules. Thanks again, now I understand! :)

Comment: Alternatively, use `Solve[{a == 25, x^2 == a}, x, {a}]`, i.e., solve for `x` while eliminating `a`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, this is good way not to show `a` in the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two workarounds

```
Solve[x^2 == a, x] /. Flatten@Solve[a == 25]
```

and

```
With[{a = 25}, Solve[{x^2 == a}, x]]
```

Comment: Yes, both of these do work, thanks. Am I doing it wrong, then? Is that the intended behavior of `Solve`?

Comment: @vpprof there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your logic. For example if you tried `Solve[{a == 25, x^2 == a}, {x, a}]` you would get an answer. I am not sure if you wanted to include `a` in the last spot of `Solve` or not